# Python ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, numpy

```
a = np.random.randint(1, 10, (3,3))
b = np.random.randint(1, 10, (3,3))
c = None

l1 = [a, b, c]

for l in l1:
  if l is None:
    l1.remove(l)
  l1
```

I am getting ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all(). Since it already checks if l is none then why can it not remove it ?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.** _Since it already checks if l is none then why can it not remove it ?_ What does checking if `l` (which is explicitly mentioned as a bad name in PEP 8, by the way) is `None` have to do with the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10062954/valueerror-the-truth-value-of-an-array-with-more-than-one-element-is-ambiguous)

Comment: Look at `a is None`

Answer (score 1):

Basically your code does `[a, b, c].remove(c)` which does something like:

```
for x in [a, b, c]:
    if x == c:
        # remove x
```

The `if x == c:` breaks in the first case where `x` is `a`: `a == None` returns a new array.

That's why you get that message. Marcel's answer has the right fix. You shouldn't be modifying (with `remove`) a list as you iterate over it anyway.

Comment: why does it return a new array ?

Comment: @WuDaozi because numpy arrays override `==` and most other binary operators to return new arrays after performing an elementwise calculation.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this happening is that when trying to remove `l` (which is `None`) from `l1`, `remove(l)` goes through the array and checks if each element is equal to `l`. As soon as it finds this element, it will remove it from the list. In doing comparisons it encounters `a`, and checks if `a == None` is true. This creates an array of booleans with whether or not each element of `l` is None. When you use this in an if statement, it is ambiguous whether or not it true.

Instead use

```
l1 = [l for l in l1 if not type(l) == type(None)]
```

to filter out all `None`s in your list.

Comment: Your new code is correct, but `l is None` doesn't create an array of booleans, it's impossible to override `is`.